# Dockerized Angular 4 and Django is compiled successfully but localhost:4200 is not working

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, docker

I would like to dockerize Angular 4 frontend with Django backend and postgresql database. At this moment my files looks as shown below. I am note sure if this is done properly? When I try `docker-compose up` I get information that both frontend with Angular 4 and backend with Django started successfully. Unfortunately when I open http://localhost:4200 it doesn't work (localhost:8001 seems working):

```
Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection
```

My logs:

```
django_1   | Django version 1.11, using settings 'project.settings'
django_1   | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8001/
django_1   | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
angular_1  | ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **                                                             
angular_1  | Time: 20657ms
angular_1  | chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 232 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 222 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.6 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.41 MB [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
angular_1  | webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Structure of my files:

```
├── Backend
│   ├── AI
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── Dockerfile
├── Frontend
│   └── angularProject
        ├── Dockerfile
│       └── all files in my angular project 
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

`Dockerfile` from frontend:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`Dockerfile` from main directory:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: aso
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 MainDirectory/backend/myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
  angular:
    build: MainDirectory/frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

Listening:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e214d1966286        dockerproj_angular   "npm start"              2 hours ago         Up 36 seconds       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp   dockerpri_angular_1
b9fa457bd119        dockerproj_django    "python3 PROJ/backe..."   2 hours ago         Up 37 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   dockerpri_django_1
e36635448b6e        postgres            "docker-entrypoint..."   2 hours ago         Up 37 seconds       5432/tcp                 dockerpri_db_1
docker exec e214d1966286 ss -ltn
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN     0      128              127.0.0.11:42403                    *:*     
LISTEN     0      128               127.0.0.1:4200                     *:*
```

**SOLUTION:**
I changed in `package.json` `"start": "ng serve"` to `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"`.

Comment: Have you considered using nginx instead of node? It doesn't depend on any npm stuff. You just copy the built files into a directory in your nginx container and it gets served. Nginx defaults to port 80, so keep that in mind. I never messed with additional configs but you can include a config file for nginx to set stuff like the port it listens to. This is as basic as it gets. http://queirozf.com/entries/angular-2-app-running-on-nginx-on-docker-a-simple-example

Comment: What is the app serving angular? Is it listening to :4200?

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear I was trying with nginx, too. Unfortunately I had some problems so I decided to try in this way. I am going to deploy it on Heroku. I am note sure which method is more optimal?

Comment: @Robert How can I check it?

Comment: Your node app must be told to listen that port in its .js code. Also you can check the listening port as this: `docker exec <container-id> ss -ltn`

Comment: I have updated my post. It seems to be listening.

Comment: Eureka! That is the problem. It must listen to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. Check the node app

Comment: When docker maps ports, it do it to the eth0 interface of the container, not to its localhost. That is a tipical mistake

Comment: @Robert sorry for the late response. How can I change it to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I have changed `package.json` from `"start": "ng serve"` to `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"`. Thank you for your help. You can create answer and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: You're welcome @Wahtdbogh !

Comment: I'm trying to deploy it on Heroku but I have some problems. If you want to take a look here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968740/deploying-project-in-docker-with-angular-4-django-and-postgresql ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the interface that your node app is listening to.

When docker maps a port, it does it between host interfaces and the eth0 container interface, and not to the localhost interface.

So, as you stated, changing this:

```
"start": "ng serve"
```

to:

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0".
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: It's interesting because I've used Docker Compose with Angular CLI and I didn't have a problem with using localhost 4200.